# World Map API for info graphic

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have a set of geographical coordinates which I'd like to visualize as a SVG  world map, where each Country has a colour which is lighter or darker according to the amount of points residing in it. Being able to display the number of points for each Country on hover would be a plus. Is there any library which offer similar functionalities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.owl-hollow.net) to implement the map you want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any library, but they way I handled a similar problem once was to use a paletted graphics format. Then I assigned each state  -- I was doing states in the country rather than countries in the world, but same idea) -- I assigned each state a number in the palette. Then I determined the appropriate color for each country, and simply changed the pallette. Each state then magically changed to the new color. In practice many palette entries mapped to identical colors, but so what?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Jay.  A technical term you might want to learn is "choropleth".  Among the pieces in this area I've written is http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-svgclientside/ .  My summary:  I think you're likely to find doing your own programming in this domain plenty satisfying.